SingletonRouter is Null using NextJS13 imported from "next/router"
Context
I'm trying to cancel the routing change when the user leaves the page without saving changes. To achieve this in Next.js, I need to listen to routing changes and cancel them using a handler function as middleware to intercept the route change
Like this:
import { Router } from 'next/router'

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleChange)

in order to listen and emit a handler function as middleware to intercept the route changing
Issue
I know NextJS introduced a new Router inside "next/navigation". However when I attempt to import the legacy Router from "next/router" like this:
import SingletonRouter from 'next/router';
the singleton shows a null.
I need to access that singleton in order to prevent routing changes.
I need to access that Router singleton in order to prevent routing changes.

SingletonRouter exist in the Next 13 using pages directories
You will be able to access the Router legacy hook module from 'next/router" but to access SingletonRouter to emit events, you must use pages folder structure for routing instead of the app folders.
The new Router from 'next/navigation" does not allow you to prevent the routing.
As a workaround, I found that some Next.js projects mix the pages folder and app folder, but I do not recommend this approach.
Here is a example of a repository that is accesses SingletonRouter using pages with Nextjs 13:
https://github.com/codeBelt/warn-unsaved-changes-leaving-web-page-nextjs/tree/typescript

First.. If you use app router. You need to use next/navigation. If you use the pages directory, you can use the next/router package.
Set up state to track changes: First, manage a state variable that tracks whether there are unsaved changes.
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function YourComponent() {
    const [hasUnsavedChanges, setHasUnsavedChanges] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();


    const toggleUnsavedChanges = () => setHasUnsavedChanges(!hasUnsavedChanges);
}

Use the beforePopState method to intercept route changes. You can prompt the user with a confirmation dialog to ensure they want to leave the page with unsaved changes.
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
            if (router.asPath !== url && hasUnsavedChanges) {
                if (window.confirm('You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?')) {
                    // Allow the route change
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Prevent the route change
                    router.events.emit('routeChangeError');
                    throw 'Route change aborted.';
                }
            }
        }

        router.beforePopState(handleRouteChange);

        return () => {
            router.beforePopState(() => true); // Clean up the listener
        };
    }, [hasUnsavedChanges, router]);

You’ll need to adjust the state based on user interactions that affect whether there are unsaved changes. For instance, modifying a form field would set hasUnsavedChanges to true.
